Can I incrementally export individual custom events to an Open Telemetry collector without batching the whole call hierarchy?
We have a bunch of home-grown legacy infrastructure that aggregates JSON-formatted log and metrics events from Docker running on EC2, via rsyslog to a Kafka queue, where it then fans out to various metrics dashboards, 3rd party analytics services, etc.  We already have our own way of logging spans and traces and log durations that dates back at least 7 years, and we don't have the resources to rewrite all of it.
I'd like to integrate Open Telemetry, but instead of having a parallel series of agents and collectors throughout our systems, I'd love to just tap into the Kafka queue and forward from there to OTel.
It appears that I want to write a custom exporter, but unless I'm misunderstanding the API, it appears I need to centralize wrapping the creation of the trace hierarchy and use the same tracer for all the events that match that trace.  I could shard Kafka to get the common parent id onto one topic queue, and then batch all the related events in memory to emit them all at once, but this would be a fairly heavyweight approach that I'd rather avoid, if there's a way that the queue reader can be dumb about trace events and just forward them to the collector incrementally.
Possible?
